# access another class protected variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

Im writing a football manager simulator with php, [ HARD AlGORITHMS !]

i have 3 class :

**Player**

```
class Player {

protected $name;

public function addAttr($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}
}
```

**Team**

```
class Team {

protected $name;

protected $players = array();


public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function addPlayer($player) {
    $this->players[] = $player;
}

public function getPlayers() {
    print_r($this->players);
}

public function getOpponetsPosition() {
    GAME::getOpponetPlayersPosition();
}
```

and **Game**

```
class Game {

protected $t1;
protected $t2;

function setTeams($team1,$team2) {
    $this->t1 = $team1;
    $this->t2 = $team2;
}

function getOpponetPlayersPosition() {
        $this->t1->getPlayers();
}
```

}

and main script

```
require_once 'classes/CPlayer.php';
require_once 'classes/CTeam.php';
require_once 'classes/CGame.php';

$game = new Game;

$team1 = new Team;
$team1->setName("PO-1");
$team2 = new Team;
$team2->setName("PO-2");

$p1 = new Player;
$p2 = new Player;


$p1->addAttr("payam babaiy");
$p2->addAttr("parsa babaiy");

$team1->addPlayer($p1);
$team2->addplayer($p2);

$game->setTeams($team1,$team2);

$team1->getOpponetsPosition();
```

I Need to get all player positions in game with **getOpponetsPosition()** function in **Team** class

but it doesnt return values which i inputed in my main script.
am i doing this right ? is this a good approach for app im writing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is good, a few points:

#### Use constructors, they can make your life easier:

```
class Player {

    protected $name;
    
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addAttr($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

And then

```
new Player("Lionel Messi");
```

**Constructors also ensure you don't get players/teams with empty names! You get better control over what gets in your classes!**

#### Don't mix static and normal code

Your getOpponentsPosition function is not correct

```
public function getOpponetsPosition() {
    GAME::getOpponetPlayersPosition();
}
```

In fact, it shouldn't even be here, it's not the `Team`'s job to fetch the other team's positions, that would be the game's, since it contains both.

**[See this gist for how I would have accomplished your goal.](https://gist.github.com/2662357)**

Comment: Thank you, for your tip and and for your answer :) i got the idea :)

Comment: Well, i have to say i learned a a lot from your code, i appreciate your help on this. thanks dude :)

Answer (score 3):

No, you are calling a static function, `GAME::getOpponetPlayersPosition();` so `$this` inside that function is not defined.